# Linq to Entities and POCO foreign key relations mapping (1 to 0..1) problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

For my ASP.NET MVC 2 application I use Entity Framework 1.0 as my data access layer (repository). But I decided I want to return POCO. For the first time I have encountered a problem when I wanted to get a list of Brands with their optional logos. Here's what I did:

```
public IQueryable<Model.Products.Brand> GetAll()
    {
        IQueryable<Model.Products.Brand> brands = from b in EntitiesCtx.Brands.Include("Logo")
                                                  select new Model.Products.Brand()
                                                         {
                                                             BrandId = b.BrandId,
                                                             Name = b.Name,
                                                             Description = b.Description,
                                                             IsActive = b.IsActive,
                                                             Logo = /*b.Logo != null ? */new Model.Cms.Image()
                                                                    {
                                                                        ImageId = b.Logo.ImageId,
                                                                        Alt = b.Logo.Alt,
                                                                        Url = b.Logo.Url
                                                                    }/* : null*/
                                                         };
        return brands;
    }
```

You can see in the comments what I would like to achieve. It worked fine whenever a `Brand` had a `Logo` otherwise it through an exception that you can assign null to the non-nullable type int (for Id). My workaround was to use nullable in the POCO class but that's not natural - then I have to check not only if `Logo` is null in my Service layer or Controllers and Views but mostly for `Logo.ImageId.HasValue`. It's not justified to have a non `null` `Logo` property if the id is `null`.

Can anyone think of a better solution?

Comment: If it's not valid for Logo to be non-null if ImageId is null, then that would indicate a problem with your underlying database. If your EF ORM is mapping the ImageId property of the Logo object to Nullable<int> it would be because the column in the database accepts nulls, but if it is a key field, it shouldn't accept nulls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have another workaround for this. Since in some cases the Image (the class for Logo property) can't be `null` and in some it can I decided to add some inheritance to my model of the Image. Here's what I've done:

```
public class OptionalImage
{
    public long? ImageId
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [DisplayName("Obraz")]
    [StringLength(200, ErrorMessage = "Url jest za długi")]
    [RegularExpression(@".*\.(jpg|gif|png|jpeg|tif|tiff|JPG|GIF|PNG|JPEG|TIF|TIFF)$", ErrorMessage = "Rozszerzenie pliku jest nieprawidłowe. Dopuszczone to: .jpg, .gif, .png, .jpeg, .tif, .tiff")]
    public string Url
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [StringLength(200, ErrorMessage = "Tekst alternatywny jest za długi")]
    [DisplayName("Tekst alternatywny")]
    public string Alt
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class Image : OptionalImage
{
    public new long ImageId
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Then my repository returns a nullable Id only for the objects that have 0..1 relation with Image - like Brand. But a Product which has a required DefaultImage property will use Image without nullable Id which is corresponding to the database and business logic design.

The `GetAll` method in the repository now looks like this (thanks @omoto for the tip):

```
public IQueryable<Model.Products.Brand> GetAll()
    {
        IQueryable<Model.Products.Brand> brands = from b in EntitiesCtx.Brands
                                                  let logo = EntitiesCtx.Images.FirstOrDefault(c => c.ImageId == b.Logo.ImageId)
                                                  select new Model.Products.Brand()
                                                         {
                                                             BrandId = b.BrandId,
                                                             Name = b.Name,
                                                             Description = b.Description,
                                                             IsActive = b.IsActive,
                                                             Logo = new Model.Cms.OptionalImage()
                                                                    {
                                                                        ImageId = logo.ImageId,
                                                                        Alt = logo.Alt,
                                                                        Url = logo.Url
                                                                    }
                                                         };
        return brands;
    }
```

For products instead of `new Model.Cms.OptionalImage()` I will use `new Model.Cms.Image()` and since the value of `ImageId` database filed in that case can't be null it will work fine and everything will be natural in the controllers and views. 
I think this kind of workaround suits my needs very well. Still if anyone has a better solution feel free to reply.

Answer (score 1):

just a option

```
public IQueryable<Model.Products.Brand> GetAll()
{
    IQueryable<Model.Products.Brand> brands = from b in EntitiesCtx.Brands
                                              let logo =EntitiesCtx.Logos.First(c=>c.LogoId==b.LogoId);
                                              select new Model.Products.Brand()
                                                     {
                                                         BrandId = b.BrandId,
                                                         Name = b.Name,
                                                         Description = b.Description,
                                                         IsActive = b.IsActive,
                                                         Logo = /*b.Logo != null ? */new Model.Cms.Image()
                                                                {
                                                                    ImageId = logo.ImageId,
                                                                    Alt = logo.Alt,
                                                                    Url = logo.Url
                                                                }/* : null*/
                                                     };
    return brands;
}
```

I guess it's better than square select brandsXlogos, instead of this I propose to use JOIN
Let me know please if you'll find this helpful

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - it sure is better than hardcoding the navigation string for Logo property.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to not allow null logos in the database in the first place and have a special logo id=0 in the database that is the no-logo logo.  Put that on any brand for which you don't have a logo. i.e. Null Value pattern.

If you don't like having a hard coded id, create a bit value "IsNullLogo" on the logo and use that to find the logo id initially (since it might have a different ID in production to development ...).

Comment: Well if I don't allow nulls in my DB for Logo then if I insert 0 I will violate the foreign key constraint since there's no image with that id. And adding and Image with id 0 just for such cases is definitely not a good solution.. Think of allowing users to manage the images. I would have to check everywhere if they're not trying to delete or update my holly No 1. Things get messy.

Comment: You have a special system logo in the database so there is no violation.  You don't let users manipulate this special image (or any other special system images).  This is neither uncommon nor hard.

Comment: I know this is a common solution and it's justified in many scenarios. It's just more natural for me to check for nulls than to have a special database record for that. Why else would I need this record than to check if a Brand (or Product or whatever) does not have a Logo? For that purpose I don't think it's a good solution to have a special record in DB. If I want to use a default image for Brands that don't have logos that's something I would like to have in the presentation layer and not the DB. So still I prefer to check for null.